# How to Match Exact Word for match Simly in Chat application

Tags: java, android

Hey I Have some Problem to Find Exact Imotion(Facebook) for That Smily Code..
I put my Snippat Code :

```
private static final HashMap<String, Integer> smilyRegexMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

static{
        smilyRegexMap.put( ":-)" , R.drawable.fb_smile);
        smilyRegexMap.put( ":)",R.drawable.fb_smile);
        smilyRegexMap.put( ":-]" , R.drawable.fb_smile);

        smilyRegexMap.put( ":-(", R.drawable.fb_frown);
        smilyRegexMap.put( ":(" , R.drawable.fb_frown);
        smilyRegexMap.put( ":-[" , R.drawable.fb_frown);

        smilyRegexMap.put( ":-P" , R.drawable.fb_tounge);
        smilyRegexMap.put( ":p", R.drawable.fb_tounge);

        smilyRegexMap.put( ":-D" , R.drawable.fb_grin);
        smilyRegexMap.put( ":D" , R.drawable.fb_grin);

        smilyRegexMap.put( ":-O" , R.drawable.fb_gasp);
        smilyRegexMap.put( ":*" , R.drawable.fb_gasp);

        smilyRegexMap.put( ";-)" , R.drawable.fb_wink);
        smilyRegexMap.put( ";)" , R.drawable.fb_wink);
        smilyRegexMap.put( ":putnam:" , R.drawable.fb_putnam);   
    }
```

//=========================================================

```
public static CharSequence addSmileySpans(Context ch, CharSequence your_recieved_message)
{
    //smilyRegexMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    System.out.println("==In Spannable Function..........");
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(your_recieved_message);

    System.out.println("==================Size of Smily  : "+ smilyRegexMap.size());
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Iterator it = smilyRegexMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it.next();

        Pattern mPattern = Pattern.compile((String) pairs.getKey(),Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher(your_recieved_message);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            Bitmap smiley = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ch.getResources(), ((Integer) pairs.getValue()));
            builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(smiley), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
}   
    return builder;
}
```

And I have Call This Function :

```
addSmileySpans(this,"Hi i m Happy :-)  ;-)  :p   :putnam:  ");
```

===>>  My Problem is That when i Enter :putnam:   then this get Result like

Hi i m Happy [image]  [image]  [image]   [image][image]

//===========================================

Ookeyyy... Now i Use this Code  :::

```
Bitmap smiley = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ch.getResources(), ((Integer) pairs.getValue()));
Object[] spans = builder.getSpans(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), ImageSpan.class);
if (spans == null || spans.length == 0) {
   builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(smiley), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
```

But its Give Some Error ::

When Enter    :putnam:
its Result is            [image]utnam:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should sort you smiles in order from "biggest smile code" to "smallest smile code".
2. When you find next pattern just check, if this piece of text already covered with span:

```
Object[] spans = builder.getSpans(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Object.class);
if (spans == null || spans.length == 0) {
    //add new image span here
}
```

Comment: yes ,  your Solution very near to my Problem.. can u explain more Clear.  Because now i enter :putnam:   that give Two Same Image

Comment: alse explain why yot use builder.getSpans( , , Object.class); m not understand wht is Object.class??

Thanks

Comment: `Object.class` param just marks to return all possible spans. If you have only images than you can use `ImageSpan.class`.

Comment: And what problem do you have now - provide sample string and result please.

Comment: i Edit my Question With ur new Code....  everything working well but only this :putnam:  not working...

Comment: You did not sort smiles order. Finding smiles patterns should go from biggest to smallest. (Now you first find ":p", replace it with span and then obviously did not find anything in string "utnam:")